# Instagram Graph API "official badged partner"

Tags: graph, instagram, instagram-api, schedule, instagram-graph-api

we are planning a tool with which you can automatically post to instagram and facebook.
Do we have to be official badged partners to get access to the instagram graph api? Or does one have nothing to do with the other?

I read that Instagram/Facebook does not accept new partners for community management apps, which is fine for us, if you can still use graph api and develop an app that allows our business users to post automatically in the correct way.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, to access the API you must be a Facebook approved partner. In order to get approval you must meet the requirements as an adtech partner. https://www.facebook.com/business/marketing-partners/adtech-speciality-requirements